# C# Displaying a ViewBag based on ViewModel controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, code-first

I have a ViewModel that displays the items in the cart CartItems and one that displays the total cost. My if statement that I currently have doesn't work, why is this and how do i go about fixing it? CartItems is a List. Im trying to make it so that if there is no items in the cart, the message CART EMPTY is displayed

```
    ShoppingCartViewModel viewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel
    {
        CartItems = cart.GetCartItems(),
        CartTotal = cart.GetTotal()
    };


if (viewModel.CartItems == null)
{
    ViewBag.CartStatus = "CART EMPTY";
}
else
{
    ViewBag.CartStatus = "Cart Has item, proceed";
}
```

Comment: What's the point of using `ViewBag` when you have a view model? What's the point of using `ViewBag` even in an ASP.NET MVC application? I don't see any.

Comment: If the viewbag has items, then allow user to proceed using a viewbag or inform them basket is empty, would you recommend a better way to do this?

Comment: And is `CartItems ` actually `null` or just an empty collection (what does `GetCartItems()` do?)

Comment: An empty collection, I wasn't sure how to say If emptyCollection, GetCartItems fetches all of  the products added by the user to the basket @StephenMuecke

Comment: `if (viewModel.CartItems.Count == 0)` (or `.Count()` depending if its `IList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your method always returns an empty collection you probably want to check against that instead of `null`:

```
if (viewModel.CartItems.Any())
{
    ViewBag.CartStatus = "CART EMPTY";
}
else
{
    ViewBag.CartStatus = "Cart Has item, proceed";
}
```

Also this `ViewBag` is just horrible. My eyes are bleeding every single time I see it. You've got a view model, why not just have a `CartStatus` tring property on it and update it accordingly?

Comment: I almost made a silly mistake of just copy and pasting instead of trying to understand, this is exactly what I need, just in reverse haha. Thanks a lot, so if its a list, I can just use .Any to check if the list has any items in it?

Comment: That will depend on what the method returning this list is doing and how it is implemented. If it is properly implemented it should return an empty list instead of `null`. If it is crappy written it will return `null` and your code will crash when you try to execute the `.Any()` extension method on it. So just make sure that you are properly implementing the method.

Comment: Aaah okay, thanks a lot for your answer, it works perfectly, can't + it for 7 mins

Comment: I have another question. updated my question with it in a moment, wondering if you could help again? Same thing but this time I'm not sure how to pass this to another controller.

Comment: You should probably start a new question.

Comment: It's kind of related, didn't want to ask another question, thought that would have been redundant but Im happy to if you don't want to pile onto this question @DarinDimitrov

Comment: The thing is that if you modify pretty much your original question it looses the original context and the original answer. In the new question you could always provide a link to this one for additional context if necessary.

Comment: Fair enough, ignore my edit and ill start a new question